# Joomla scriptfile on package

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="package" version="3.0">
    <name>JFCore package</name>
    <author>Joomla Freelance</author>
    <creationDate>June 2014</creationDate>
    <packagename>jfcore</packagename>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <url>http://joomla-freelance.com</url>
    <packager>Joomla Freelance</packager>
    <packagerurl>http://joomla-freelance.com/downloads.html</packagerurl>
    <description>Combine multiples functions</description>
    <update>http://joomla-freelance.com/update/packages/pkg_jfcore.xml</update>
        <files folder="packages">
            <file type="plugin" id="jfcore" group="authentication">plg_authentication_jfcore.zip</file>
            <file type="plugin" id="jfcore" group="captcha">plg_captcha_jfcore.zip</file>
            <file type="plugin" id="jfcore" group="content">plg_content_jfcore.zip</file>
            <file type="plugin" id="jfcore" group="editors">plg_editors_jfcore.zip</file>
            <file type="plugin" id="jfcore" group="extension">plg_extension_jfcore.zip</file>
            <file type="plugin" id="jfcore" group="finder">plg_finder_jfcore.zip</file>
            <file type="plugin" id="jfcore" group="quickicon">plg_quickicon_jfcore.zip</file>
            <file type="plugin" id="jfcore" group="search">plg_search_jfcore.zip</file>
            <file type="plugin" id="jfcore" group="system">plg_system_jfcore.zip</file>
            <file type="plugin" id="jfcore" group="user">plg_user_jfcore.zip</file>
            <file type="plugin" id="jfcore" group="jfcore">plg_jfcore_jfcore.zip</file>
        </files>
</extension>
```

I would like to know if we can use a scriptfile on package like this:

```
<scriptfile>jfcore.scriptfile.php</scriptfile>
```

I tried but nothing happened. My class was class `pkgJfcoreInstallerScript`
I search everywhere without answers.

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

class pkgJfcoreInstallerScript {

    function install($parent) {
        echo '<p>'. JText::_('PKG_JFCORE_INSTALL') . '</p>';
    }

    function uninstall($parent) {
        echo '<p>'. JText::_('PKG_JFCORE_UNINSTALL') .'</p>';
    }

    function update($parent) {
        echo '<p>'. JText::_('PKG_JFCORE_UPDATE') .'</p>';
    }

    function preflight($type, $parent) {
        echo '<p>'. JText::sprintf('PKG_JFCORE_PREFLIGHT', $type) .'</p>';
    }

    function postflight($type, $parent) {
        echo '<p>'. JText::sprintf('PKG_JFCORE_POSTFLIGHT', $type) .'</p>';
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code from the script file as it might be the code within it that wasn't working

Comment: Simple, for testing if scriptfile is loaded.

Comment: Ok you script file looks fine. Is it in the same location as your XML file?

Comment: Yes, pkg_jfcore.xml
     jfcore.scriptfile.php
     --packages/

Comment: I will try again now to see.

Comment: Try changing `pkgJfcoreInstallerScript` to `Pkg_JfcoreInstallerScript`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only just noticed, but in your script file, you need to change the class name from:

```
pkgJfcoreInstallerScript
```

to this:

```
Pkg_JfcoreInstallerScript
```